# Intersection of certain parabolic subgroups in $G$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a simple (linear) algebraic group over $\mathbb C$.
Let us fix a maximal torus $H \subset G$ and let $w_0 \in N_G(H)=\{g \in G: gH=Hg\}$ be such that

- the class of $w_0$ in $N_G(H)/H$ is the longest element in the Weyl group,
- $w_0^{-1}=w_0$ as an element of $N_G(H)$.

Consider a maximal parabolic subgroup $P_- \subset G$ such that its opposite parabolic subgroup $P_+$ is given by
$$
P_+=w_0P_-w_0.
$$
Consider also the isomorphism $L_{w_0}: G \to G$ given by the left multiplication by $w_0$. We define
$$
L_{w_0}P_-:=\operatorname{im}\left(L_{w_0}|_{P_-}\right).
$$
What can we say about the dimension, as an affine subvariety of $G$, of $P_+ \cap L_{w_0}P_-$?

Comment: Why would $L_{w_0}P_-$ be a subgroup? Its doesn't even contain the identity element.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop you right! I've edited the question

Comment: The intersection seems to be always empty.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop maybe it's trivial but I can't see the argument about the triviality of the intersection